# AttributeError: '_LinearColormaps' object has no attribute 'OrRd'

Tags: python, folium

**full error message**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-d5da18d2c9f9> in <module>()
----> 1 colormap_ro = linear.OrRd.scale(
      2     dataRO.Patients.min(),
      3     dataRO.Patients.max())
      4 
      5 colormap_ro

AttributeError: '_LinearColormaps' object has no attribute 'OrRd'
```

I get this error message when run this code.

```
colormap_ro = linear.OrRd.scale(
    dataRO.Patients.min(),
    dataRO.Patients.max())
    colormap_ro
```

I try to create color scale for my chronopleth map. after get this error message I uninstall folium version 0.5 and install version 0.2 but error message occur again. I try it in python version 2 and 3 and same thing happen.

How to solve this. plz help me

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

With branca 0.3.0 they changed the names of colortables. Use

linear.OrRd_03 , linear.OrRd_04 ....